# Cypher: Can't get grouped node counts from connected nodes

Tags: count, neo4j, aggregate, cypher

Apologies for the likelihood that this is a repeat question, but I perused questions already asked and either couldn't find one that related to my issue or couldn't figure out HOW they related to my issue.  I'm also a cypher neophyte so this is also likely a very simple question.

I'm trying to determine the name of each container, the total number of containers, and the number of items in each container so that I can generate a pie graph representing the distribution of items amongst containers.  The queries I've constructed so far give me a true count of the items, but either give me a count of 1 for the containers (such as the query below) or return the container count with the same value as the items count.

```
START c=node:internal_auto_index( TYPE = 'CONTAINERS' ) 
WITH c, COUNT( c.name ) as containerCount
MATCH i-[INSTANCE__CONTAINERS]->c 
RETURN c.name as containerName, containerCount, COUNT(i) as items, ( COUNT(i) / containerCount ) as percentage
ORDER BY c.name
```

What is it I'm doing wrong?  Thanks in advance for your time.

Cheers,

Jon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of the first query has two expressions. The first expression **c** serves as the key of the group to which the aggregation function **count()** of the second expression is applied. Since each **c** represents a group of a single container, the aggregation function **count** would certainly be evaluated to 1 rather than the total number of containers.

The easy way to fix this is to just return the count of the container in the first query and carried it forward to the second query,

```
START c=node:internal_auto_index( TYPE = 'CONTAINERS' ) 
WITH  COUNT(*) as containerCount
START c=node:internal_auto_index( TYPE = 'CONTAINERS' ) 
MATCH i-[INSTANCE__CONTAINERS]->c 
RETURN c.name as containerName, containerCount, COUNT(i) as items, ( COUNT(i) / containerCount ) as percentage
ORDER BY c.name
```

I know it looks a bit redundant, but I don't think there is a way to return each container and the total number of container in a single row as a query result.

Comment: I was actually able to make further corrections to the query by applying the same technique to the total items count, thusly: START i=node:internal_auto_index( TYPE = 'ITEMS' ) 
WITH COUNT(*) as totalItems
START c=node:internal_auto_index( TYPE = 'CONTAINERS' ) 
WITH  COUNT(*) as totalContainers, totalItems
START c=node:internal_auto_index( TYPE = 'CONTAINERS' ) 
MATCH i-[INSTANCE__CONTAINERS]->c 
RETURN c.name as containerName, totalContainers, COUNT(i) as containerItems, totalItems
ORDER BY c.name